# Where are the RGB values stored in this array?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, rgb, lockbits

I've been using the following sub in my control that I'm creating to let me modify the pixels in a bitmap faster:

```
    Protected Sub LockForMemory()
        idata = ime.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, ime.Width, ime.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, ime.PixelFormat)
        ipoint = idata.Scan0

        ibytes = Math.Abs(idata.Stride) * ime.Height
        ReDim irgbvalues(ibytes - 1)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ipoint, irgbvalues, 0, ibytes)
    End Sub
```

All of that works, later when I go to retrieve the actual image after manipulation, it works fine as well.  The problem is setting those actual pixels.

What is this array of?  I know that it's filled with `Integers` but what does each indice represent?  At first I thought it was setup like this:

***Array-> [R of Pixel 0,0][G of Pixel 0,0][B of Pixel 0,0][R of Pixel 2,0][G of Pixel 2,0][B of Pixel 2,0]***

This doesn't seem to work right, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the value of ime.PixelFormat.  Each pixel may be represented as RGB, ARGB, palette look-up index, etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx

Also, you need to be careful of byte-order.  The bytes would likely be in little-endian byte-order, but it depends on your target platform.

For Format32bppArgb, this may shed some light on the format:

[PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb seems to have wrong byte order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104461/pixelformat-format32bppargb-seems-to-have-wrong-byte-order)

Comment: So, after taking a look into it, I found that it is the `Format32bppArgb` Pixel Format.  With that information, could you elaborate a little more on the subject for me?

Comment: Oh, OK.  That makes sense now.  Thanks for the help!  +1 and a check for you!